# Системный вызов на ассемблере

Tags: c, ассемблер, linux

Есть программа hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
        printf("Hello!\n");
}
```

Результат работы - печать сообщения "Hello!":

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.c && ./hello
Hello!
```

Как сделать то же самое, используя системный вызов, через встроенный ассемблер gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>

void main()
{
    const char s[] = "Hello!\n";

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "int $0x80"
        :
        : "a"(__NR_write), "b"(STDOUT_FILENO), "c"(s), "d"(sizeof(s))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Системный вызов можно сделать прямо из C:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
    char hello[] = "Hello!\n";

    write(STDOUT_FILENO, hello, sizeof(hello));
}
```