# Отладка без отладчика и печати

Tags: отладка, c, linux

Как отлаживать код на С, если нет возможности подключить отладчик и выводить печати в лог?

Comment: А что за программа, если не секрет? 

Comment: Это что-то вроде упаковщика UPX.

Comment: Ну так и что мешает для отладки открыть какой-нибудь файл и дампить лог в него? Или прямо в stdout?

Comment: Утилита состоит из двух частей: сжатия и распаковки. Сжатие - это обычная консольная программа, там все просто. А распаковка входит в состав исполняемого файла и выполняется еще до загрузки распаковываемого кода.

Comment: Ну и что? Что вам мешает писать что-то куда-то?

Comment: В распаковке нет СRT, нечем писать.

Comment: Эмм, я с линуксом не разбирался, но я абсолютно не верю, что без CRT выводить нельзя. std, надеюсь, вы никуда не дели?=)

Comment: Открыть и писать в сокет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно задействовать сигналы:

```
#include <signal.h>

#define ASSERT(condition) if (!(condition)) raise(SIGTRAP);

/* Сработает в случае ошибки */
ASSERT(0 == 1)
```

Если по какой-то причине нет CRT, можно использовать [системные вызовы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/350/) для печати.

Answer (score 0):

Если у приложения нет UI, то никак. А вообще, я думаю, что такое не бывает. В смысле, всегда есть возможность либо что-то напечатать хоть куда-нибудь, либо подключиться отладчиком.